# не работает hover с svg

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Есть вот такая верстка и такие стили. При ховере нужно, чтобы стрелка появлялась внутри ссылки, но она не появляется. Как это исправить?

```css
.header-text-links a {
 display: block;
 width: 278px;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid #fab608;
 color: #fab608;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Futura Demi";
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
 display: none;
}
.header-text-links a:hover {
 color: white;
 background: #fab608;
 text-decoration: none;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
.header-text-links a:hover .header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class = "header-text-links">
<a class = "header-text-links__works" href = "<?php echo get_page_link( 20 ); ?>">Наши работы<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: .svg-inline--fa это в консоли браузера посмотрели что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.header-text-links a {
 display: block;
 width: 278px;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid #fab608;
 color: #fab608;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Futura Demi";
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-text-links a .svg-inline--fa {
 display: none;
}
.header-text-links a:hover {
 color: white;
 background: #fab608;
 text-decoration: none;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
.header-text-links a:hover .svg-inline--fa {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<div class = "header-text-links">
<a class = "header-text-links__works" href = "<?php echo get_page_link( 20 ); ?>">Наши работы<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
</div>
```